# ASP.NET MVC - The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've renamed some views in my MVC project and then changed the controller to reflect the change but for some reason it still cannot find the view.

My action is as follows:

```
 // GET: Accounts
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Find", db.Accounts.ToList());
        }
```

And as you can see from this screenshot, the view is there where it should be:[image: Views]

Is there something I've missed?

Comment: What controller class is that action in?

Comment: What is the controller called? Have you got any custom routing?

Comment: It's in an AccountsController, there's no custom routing and yeah I've rebuilt - if I rename the ActionResult to the same as the view it works, but I thought I didn't need to do that?

Comment: And what is the URL you are using to access this method?

Comment: With that URL, the action needs to be called `Find` too.

Comment: Ah ok, so telling it what view to use won't re-route it?

Comment: No, that's just telling the action which view to use when rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in MVC, the routing says you access an action in this format:

```
http://server/controller/action
```

Changing the view used doesn't affect the routing at all. So if you want to access the action, you can either use a proper URL:

```
http://server/accounts/index
```

This should also work but depends on your routing as Index is often the default action:

```
http://server/accounts
```

Alternatively you could add a custom route just for that action.